# SIMADO GDT11 GSM Modem..Configure smskannel.conf file

Tags: gsm, modem

I need to edit the `smskannel.conf` file but I don't know the following things.
The below are configurations for Huawei modem I need it for Simado gdt11 gsm modem.

## SMSC MODEM GSM

Comment: Did you intend to add a config file to this? Bear in mind it is likely to be off-topic here, unless it is about programming. Also, is it really related to your `php` tag?

Comment: I have to add the smsc in the config file so that i will be able to send sms and i know its not related to php

Comment: I suspect this question +might+ be better on _Super User_, in that case - although you are likely to need more detail. As I say, your post mentions a configuration below, and then you haven't added any to the question.